# Table design for efficiently retrieving "most recent row" per FK'd item whose PK is a GUID

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index

Database is SQLAzure

I've a recent requirement to store incremental updates in status against an Order item, whose primary key is a GUID (stored as an nvarchar(36) :/ ). An OrderStatusLog entry might happen at any time, it would have minimally the OrderId, ChangeDateTime, and the new Status.

There may be hundreds of status updates per order (but realistically, probably only tens) and they're all kept for audit reasons so that at any point the questions "what were the status changes over time?" and "what was the order status at time X?" can be answerd.

It will also be queried, potentially several hundred times (but again, most likely tens), what the current (i.e the most recent row) status is. Generally the chances that a recent Order will be queried are much higher than an old order, which is where I think the Order Id being a GUID might be a nuisance, because there isn't an innate order to them (nor can I change them to be sequential) so status change records end up scattered all over the storage regardless of when they were created

I'm not so interested to know the date the change occurred for the frequent question of "what is the most recent status?" and auto numbering doesn't have to start with 1 for every different order, so the Revision column could just be a single auto inc int and it could answer the "what is the most recent row for OrderId X?". For the infrequent question of "what were all the changes in order?" an autoinc answers it too, and for or "what was the status on date X?" the date is useful, but this will be seldom asked

Does the OrderId being a GUID present a problem no matter what? Is it still worth creating a table that has a clustering index of OrderId (guid) and e.g. Revision (an auto incrementing int) as its key columns (in that order) - is it the ideal arrangement for a historical log of status changes such as this? Or should I not be trying to influence storage order, and instead be saying "well, the likely number of change records will be small, and retrieving and sorting them all every time they're needed is likely fairly inconsequential" and just nonclustering the OrderId and including the date(or revision) and status?

Note; I can't put the current status on the Order table alas (not my restriction)

Edit: some extra info on the tables:

```
Order                        --stores orders
Id NVARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY, --guid stored as string (yes.. :/ )
... other fields

OrderStatusLog               --tracks all the changes an order went through. An INSERT-only (and SELECT) table
OrderId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,    --references Oder(id) but not an FK officially because of the type mismatch
ChangeDate DATETIME,         --the time of the change in status
Status                       --the status as of time ChangeDate
```

I'll frequently want to (100s of times a day):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Status FROM OrderStatusLog WHERE OrderId = @id ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC
```

Infrequently (10s a day):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Status FROM OrderStatusLog WHERE OrderId = @id AND ChangeDate < @d ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC
```

Seldom (1 a day):

```
SELECT * FROM OrderStatusLog WHERE OrderId = @id ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC
```

99% of the time these queries would be operating on rows inserted within the past 24 hours.

---

I'm trying to decide how to index this log table given that it has a guid. My understanding of indexing in SQLS is that a clustered index influences the order of storage of rows on disk, and using GUIDs causes a bit of a nuisance with reoganizing because a GUID may naturally want to sit in the middle of existing data, meaning that data pages end up splitting. I'd like to know the implications of resource use of clustering vs nonclustering; if one indexing strategy means that inserts are more costly as (on average) they cause more data to be shuffled around disk but it makes selecting the data faster/lower cost, versus another strategy wher the insert might be cheap but the cost of selecting be much higher.

At this time the use case is just for those shown; no other uses are planned

This log table doesn't have, or seemingly need, a primary key and though infeasible that two updates would happen in the same millisecond (or whatever) as a more generic solution I'd like to know how to control for situations where updates could come in the same millisecond (i.e. I'm thinking an autoinc int column could help satisfy ORDER BY x DESC for "most recent" and then the "could be simultaneous" is moot)

---

As I've often advised others, I've looked at doing some benching of this. I created 3 tables of identical columns, made:

- one a clustered on OrderId+ChangeDate+Status,
- one a nonclustered unique on OrderId+ChangeDate include Status, and
- one a nonclustered nonunique OrderId include ChangeDate+Status

I filled each table with the same set of 100,000 records, of approx 10,000 distinct guids and ~10 status changes over a random time frame. Table load performance was roughly the same - about 33 seconds on my local SQL Express from a C# app.

I ran 100,000 iterations of the frequent query against each table, hitting every Guid in each table 10 times with runtimes of 23 seconds (clustered), 22 seconds (nonclustered OI-CD include S) and 28 seconds (nonclustered OI include CD-S).

Index and table storage stats:

[image]

[image]

After swapping the clustered unique index on all table cols out for a clustered nonunique on OrderId+ChangeDate, and swapping the nonclustered unique on OI+CD out to be unique (and truncating all tables, backing up db, then re-loading it)

[image]

And plans:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different (but probably materially the same) suggestion from Akina would be to index on `(OrderId, ChangeDateTime) INCLUDE (Status)` since you're only selecting `Status` never filtering on it directly. This would service queries of the kind:

```
SELECT TOP 1 status
FROM sourcetable
WHERE orderid = @GUID
-- AND ChangeDateTime <= @ChangeDateTime
ORDER BY ChangeDateTime DESC
```

`GUID`s are obviously not the most ideal column to index on because of their data size, and more so because of their randomness resulting in higher fragmentation, but if it's all you have to work with then it's better to index it than not. You'll still see improved query performance with the index on it.

There's probably going to be no difference by adding an `INY IDENTITY` column to use in your index vs using the existing `DATETIME` field, as they both take up the same storage anyway.

There's also not much inherent difference between `CLUSTERED` and `NONCLUSTERED` indexing in your case, but if you have the luxury, and your examples are the most common type of querying that will be done, then go with the `CLUSTERED` index as that will provide you greater flexibility in the future with minimizing performance hits should you end up needing to `SELECT` other fields.

The exact index recommendation in that case would then be `CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_IndexName ON TableName (OrderId, ChangeDateTime)`. You're able to leverage the `UNIQUE` clause here since your `GUID` guarantees it, which can slightly help performance of the index as well.

Comment: There isn't any doubt in my mind that I will index it.. I'm trying to know more about the best type of indexing (and by consequence, table design) strategy.. i.e. cluster or not, what columns to index (whether to add an auto int revision and index that or just use the datetime), and what to include

Comment: @CaiusJard I updated my answer with some additional information regarding your questions.

Comment: Though I'm not certain that the data is automatically unique on guid+time I could look to make it a business rule that an order doesn't change status more than once a millisecond etc :)

Comment: I don't have an in-depth knowledge of how SQLS stores data, which is one of the drivers for this question. In terms of cluster indexing a guid, is it not the case that they cause problems as tables grow because of the equal likelihood that data will need to be inserted "into the middle of the table" (for want of a better description of them filling up/causing splits in pages all over the place rather than a sequential key that concentrates recent rows in fewer pages) because the table data is kept ordered by something that has no inherent order? How do we balance the cost of keeping data in ..

Comment: .. order versus the cost of having to retrieve it from all over the place and order it every time we want to use it? Is an index on fewer keys, but that includes more data cheaper to use in this regard?

Comment: @CaiusJard Apologies, I was assuming your `GUID` is the primary key in this case but forgot this is a log of `status` changes per `Order`. So yes in that case you wouldn't be able to guarantee use of the `UNIQUE` constraint, though from an application / business logic perspective, it does seem it *should* be impossible for the same `Order` to change `status` twice at the same exact time. But I don't like to live on assumptions, so unless you can guarantee it, it won't make much of a difference creating the index without the `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: To your other questions, the **page splits** is what my answer refers to when talking about **index fragmentation**. Yes that's going to occur more often with a `GUID`, regardless if it's the **CLUSTERED** or a **NONCLUSTERED** index. The only reason it could be worse of an issue as the **CLUSTERED** index is because any additional **NONCLUSTERED** indexes will store your **CLUSTERED** index's key as a reference (bloating your **NONCLUSTERED** indexes) and whenever a **NONCLUSTERED** index needs to do **key lookup** operations, it'll need to do that lookup on more fragmented data than if...

Comment: ...the **CLUSTERED** index was a less fragmenting data type like an `INT IDENTITY`. But it sounds like all your querying on the table (at this point in time) can be serviced with one index, so in that case it probably makes no difference if you make it **CLUSTERED** or **NONCLUSTERED**. If you have other use cases on this table though, then it's possible it'll be somewhat better to make a different field your **CLUSTERED** index to not inflate your other **NONCLUSTERED** indexes. But I'm only able to go off the information you provided so far. One thing that would be very helpful to anyone...

Comment: ...reading your question, is your exact table definition. Knowing what is your **primary key** on the table in this case may be of use. And knowing if there are other types of queries that'll be ran or if this is really the only types of use cases for this table.

Comment: I added some more info to the question

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious improvement is the creation of an index by `(OrderId, ChangeDateTime, Status)`. If your query looks like

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) status
FROM sourcetable
WHERE orderid = @GUID
-- AND ChangeDateTime <= @ChangeDateTime
ORDER BY ChangeDateTime DESC
```

then it must be fast enough - the index is covering, so the on-disk table body access not needed at all.

Comment: Given the question is about SQL Server. `SELECT TOP (1)` instead of `LIMIT 1` is the needed construct.

Comment: But the question is more about the kind of index we should create.. Clustering on OrderId and Revision with Status, or nonclustering on OrderId with Revision and Status

Comment: I'm trying to understand how guids affect clustering when theyre part of a compound index in a scenario where we're striving to know the most recent row for a given GUID, and if they cause a detriment then how we can work around it.. And if there is a sense to having the other part of a compound cluster be an autoinc int

Comment: @DanGuzman *Given the question is about SQL Server.* This affects correct syntax only. *the question is more about the kind of index we should create* Nonclustering index is more compact. And so it seems to be preferred because it is covering one.

Comment: @Akina, I don't disagree the question is about indexing, only pointing out the incorrect query syntax in your answer that may be confusing to others in a SQL Server context.

Comment: Indeed, I'm happy to adapt any syntax presented - my question is really about the different ways that data could be indexed, how it is stored on disk as a result, and how it would be used in the scenarios presented - and what is an optimal indexing strategy. It will come up a lot across the system I work on at the moment; ultimately I'm trying to balance the costs of decisions - if I do X, then will SQLS spend most of its time shuffling data on disk, if I do Y, then will it spend most of its time shuffling data in memory, and which of these is optimal for the situation?